# Cannot Access Web Interface on HP 2510G

Tags: switch, website, hp

I am currently setting up a new infrastructure with HP 2510s as edge switches and an HP E5406 as the main switch.  I also have a DHCP and DNS server running on the same network.

When i first set up one of my 2510 switches, I gave it a static IP through the console and then went to the web interface to continue my configuration.  Later, I realized that I assigned it the wrong IP address, so i went through the web interface and changed the IP address to the correct one.

Now, I can't access the web interface.  I can telnet to the switch on the new IP address, but the web interface will not load.  If I switch from static IP to DHCP, it loads the web interface.  Any ideas on what could be causing the web server in the 2510 not to load with the new static IP address?

Comment: What firmware (`show ver`)? I assume you've power cycled it? Do you have an vlans defined?

Comment: I'm running Y.11.16.  I never actually power cycled the switch, but I have reboot it a bunch through the console.

Comment: I've got 25010Gs and had problems with T.11.16 that HP still hasn't resolved. I ended up [reverting to Y.11.12](https://h10145.www1.hp.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9280A&lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesID=3356807).

Comment: Well, i powered cycled the switch and now everything is working.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to powercycle for it to take the new settings into effect for all the management interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the firmware. Just go back to the old version.